# Sum amounts based on account value

Tags: oracle, sum, lag, lead

I want to sum AMT for account = 270400 and account like ‘51%’ only when AMT is positive on account = 270400.  However, if there is an account = 513901, I want sum AMT for account = 270400 and account like ‘51%’ whether AMT is positive or negative on account = 270400. How to deploy Oracle lag/lead SQL in this case?

SUM would be = 14 in this data: (SUM 2 for 270400 and 12 for LIKE '51%")

| account | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 210897 | 1 |
| 270400 | 2 |
| 513101 | 3 |
| 513901 | 4 |
| 513901 | 5 |
| 529500 | 6 |

SUM would be = 10 in this data: (SUM -2 for 270400 and 12 for LIKE '51%")

| account | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 210897 | 1 |
| 270400 | -2 |
| 513101 | 3 |
| 513901 | 4 |
| 513901 | 5 |
| 529500 | 6 |

SUM would be = 14 in this data: (SUM 2 for 270400 and 12 for LIKE '51%")

| account | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 210897 | 1 |
| 270400 | 2 |
| 513101 | 3 |
| 514101 | 4 |
| 515101 | 5 |
| 529500 | 6 |

SUM would be = 12 in this data: (do not SUM -2 for 270400, since it is negative and account 513901 is not in the dataset, but SUM LIKE '51%' = 12)

| account | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 210897 | 1 |
| 270400 | -2 |
| 513101 | 3 |
| 514101 | 4 |
| 515101 | 5 |
| 529500 | 6 |

Comment: Please show actual sample data along with the desired result.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an English description of how to calculate the sum; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output. At the moment your question does not make sense as the value `51%` appears from nowhere, as if by magic, and then you start talking about `LAG`/`LEAD` but it is not obvious why this would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0) AS total
FROM   table_name
WHERE  account LIKE '51%'
OR     (   account = 270400
       AND (  amount >= 0
           OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE account = 513901)
           )
       )
```

Or, using analytic functions rather than `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0) AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT account,
         amount,
         COUNT(CASE account WHEN 513901 THEN 1 END) OVER () AS can_be_negative
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  account = 270400
  OR     account LIKE '51%'
)
WHERE  account LIKE '51%'
OR     amount >= 0
OR     can_be_negative > 0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=af2e1c1f8347c3ff3197b70ee467f25b)*

Comment: I really appreciate the quick answer! This did work, and I was not aware that a count "switch" could be set to determine a SUM to use. I did have to tweak it a bit, b/c it was ignoring  negative values in the inner select on '51' accounts when there was not '513901' account:    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0) AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT account,
         amount,
         COUNT(CASE account WHEN 513901 THEN 1 END) OVER () AS can_be_negative
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  account = 270400
  OR     account LIKE '51%'
)
WHERE  account like '51'
OR     can_be_negative > 0

Comment: @mikebeeman Updated the answer based on your comment. I think you missed `OR amount >= 0` from your code.